# HTML Tags Not Displaying Properly Inside Textarea

Tags: javascript, html

I have problems with my text area field.
When I select the value from database to my textarea field, the browser can't understand the HTML tags (ex: `</br>`).

This is my field :

```
<textarea id="id_get_post_description2"  maxlength="9999" name="description_post"  style="resize:none; font-size: 12pt; width:100%;  height:90%; border:1px solid #0099FF;" type="text"></textarea>
```

Comment: in javascript use => `\n`

Comment: The code in the question has no JavaScript, no apparent relation to a database, and no tags inside textarea (and no tags are allowed there by HTML syntax).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use escape characters:
Take a look at this for further information: http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes#answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the html reserved characters: http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/entity-escape-characters.php

So instead of `<`, you should use `&lt;`. This should be replaced either by your database or when generating the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help!
You give me idea to replace, and i'm fixed it with one string :)

```
description_post = description_post.replace(/<br>/g, "\n");
```